# Why is my color not changing when clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a very simple code that gives no error when I run it but the problem is, it's not doing what it's supposed to do...

When I click on the div in the middle, it should change colors...

What am I missing? Can't seem to find any typo...

```js
var panel = document.getElementById('color_panel');
document.getElementById('color_panel').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var mySwitch = document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background;
  if (mySwitch == "#76FF03") {
    document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background = "#039BE5";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background = "#76FF03";
  }
});
```

```html
<body style="background: #37474F; margin: 0;">
  <div id="color_panel" style="background: #76FF03; margin:
    auto; font-family: Century Gothic; font-size: 40px; color: #37474F;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 20px; margin-top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); text-align: center;">
    Click me!<br>or Double Click?</div>
  <button style="font-size: 10px;
    width: 100px; height: 20px; margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #FBC02D; border-radius: 5px;
    background: #E3F2FD;" id="button" onclick="transition()">
    add transition!</button>
```

Comment: Take a look at what `style.background` actualy gives you as a value. Not all browsers return the same value and they often transform input values to some form they prefer. eg if you put in hex value the browser might turn it into a `rgb()` value so it wont match your if statement

Comment: Side note if you have that much css it would probably be easier to edit/read if you use classes instead of inline styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do some basic debugging. Add a `console.log` statement to examine the value you are putting into your `if` statement and see what it actually is.

The browser is normalising it, so `mySwitch == "#76FF03"` is never true.

```js
var panel = document.getElementById('color_panel');
document.getElementById('color_panel').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var mySwitch = document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background;
  console.log(mySwitch);
  if (mySwitch == "#76FF03") {
    document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background = "#039BE5";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background = "#76FF03";
  }
});
```

```html
<body style="background: #37474F; margin: 0;">
  <div id="color_panel" style="background: #76FF03; margin:
    auto; font-family: Century Gothic; font-size: 40px; color: #37474F;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 20px; margin-top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); text-align: center;">
    Click me!<br>or Double Click?</div>
  <button style="font-size: 10px;
    width: 100px; height: 20px; margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #FBC02D; border-radius: 5px;
    background: #E3F2FD;" id="button" onclick="transition()">
    add transition!</button>
```

This type of problem is generally better handled by putting all your styles in a separate stylesheet and then adjusting the classes that an element is a member of.

```js
var panel = document.getElementById('color_panel');

panel.addEventListener("click", function() {
  panel.classList.toggle("other");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #37474F;
  margin: 0;
}

#color_panel {
  background: #76FF03;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #37474F;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#color_panel.other {
  background: #039BE5;
}

#button {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #FBC02D;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #E3F2FD;
}
```

```html
<div id="color_panel">
  Click me!<br>or Double Click?
</div>

<button style="" id="button" onclick="transition()">
    add transition!
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I wanted to use this as an example to write everything in a single file so, the given suggestion to separate them into different file is the route I usually take but was not available for this particular case. again Thanks for the help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to correct, you are getting `rgb(118, 255, 3)` in the variable `mySwitch` so its not going in the if the condition

Your code should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var panel = document.getElementById('color_panel');
    document.getElementById('color_panel').addEventListener("click", function() {
      var mySwitch = document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background;alert(mySwitch);
      if (mySwitch == "rgb(118, 255, 3)") {
        document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background = "#039BE5";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background = "#76FF03";
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mySwitch` will give the color in rgb, which you cannot compare with the stirng. remove the inline style and add instead use class. Then use `toggle` to toggle the class on every click

```js
var panel = document.getElementById('color_panel');
document.getElementById('color_panel').addEventListener("click", function() {
  panel.classList.toggle('changeColor')
});
```

```css
.divStyle {
  background: #76FF03;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #37474F;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.changeColor {
  background: #039BE5
}
```

```html
<body style="background: #37474F; margin: 0;">
  <div id="color_panel" class='divStyle'>
    Click me!<br>or Double Click?</div>
  <button style="font-size: 10px;
    width: 100px; height: 20px; margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #FBC02D; border-radius: 5px;
    background: #E3F2FD;" id="button" onclick="transition()">
    add transition!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your code is you defined the color in HEX format in HTML `#76FF03` and JavaScript returns the color in RGB format by which your `if` condition doesn't work and in your `else` condition you are again applying the same background color so you thought that your code doesn't work.

You just need to match the color with the RGB format in JavaScript. `rgb(118, 255, 3)` is the same color as `#76FF03` but in different format.

You may try this:

```js
var panel = document.getElementById('color_panel');
panel.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var mySwitch = e.target.style.background;
    if (mySwitch == "rgb(118, 255, 3)") {
        e.target.style.background = "#039BE5";
    } else {
        e.target.style.background = "#76FF03";
    }
});
```

```html
<body style="background: #37474F; margin: 0;">
    <div id="color_panel" style="background: #76FF03; margin:
    auto; font-family: Century Gothic; font-size: 40px; color: #37474F;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 20px; margin-top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); text-align: center;">
    Click me!<br>or Double Click?</div>
    <button style="font-size: 10px;
    width: 100px; height: 20px; margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #FBC02D; border-radius: 5px;
    background: #E3F2FD;" id="button" onclick="transition()">
    add transition!</button>
</body>
```

To avoid format issue you can define the color with color Name then HTML and JavaScript both return you the same result.

By the way, you just don't need to use `document.getElementById('color_panel')` again and again. As you are already assigning element in var so just use that variable for `addEventListener` and in the `addEventListener` function you may use the event variable `e` or `event` whatever name you like to use for that.

That's the optional thing if you like to do.

Answer (score -4):

The correct answer to your question is...

Your code *is* working when you click in the box.  You're code isn't incorrect and you don't have any typos.

The background color *is* changing when the box is clicked.  **It's just changing the background color to the same color that it already is**:

In your html file, in the first div:

`style="background: #76FF03;`

in your script, in the else statement:

`document.getElementById('color_panel').style.background = "#76FF03";`

Comment: My answer is correct. If the color in the else statement is changed, clicking on the square will change the background color of the square.  Try it.

Comment: Running is not the same as working. The *point* of the `if/else` is so that when the background is already "#76FF03" it changes it to the other value and *doesn't* hit the `else` part of it. The reason that doesn't work has already been explained by other answers and comments, but not by this answer. You don't even give so much as a hint about how to solve the problem.